# How can I loop through an array in SQL?

Tags: sql, for-loop, amazon-redshift

let's assume we have a table "Fruits" which is an aggregation of several tables, containing different features i.a. date, fruit, id:

| date | product | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 | Apple | 3 |
| 01.01.2023 | Peach | 2 |
| 03.01.2023 | Apple | 1 |
| 02.01.2023 | Banana | 1 |

Now I need to loop through an array fruit_list=["Apple", "Peach", "Banana"]
and get the result matching several conditions having the following form:

| date | product |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 | Apple |
| 01.01.2023 | Peach |
| 02.01.2023 | Banana |
| 03.01.2023 | Peach |

Currently I have a code something like:

```
select id from fruits
 where id is not null
and
product like '%Apple%'
 do some code: condition_1 and condition_2 and condition_3
```

But I have over 100 products and would like to run it over a loop.

```
select id from fruits
 where id is not null
 and 
 for p in fruit_list: {
select product, date
from Fruits 
where product like '%p%'
 do some code: condition_1 and condition_2 and condition_3
 }
```

Please do not try to understand the logic behind the table content, as it was chosen arbitrarily.
My point is about the loop.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you wanting to have sql do something, like update a value for that row or something?

Comment: what dbms is this?

Comment: @Kevin: it needs to be selected (subseted ) corresponding the given conditions.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: it is on AWS Redshift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my oppinion, when you need to apply condition to different products, you can perform it with 'in' statements which gets only this products
which you like to put in conditioning and it is available to do same condition for a lot of products.

Below i attached an example.

```sql
select id, product
where id is not null
and product in('Apple', 'Peach' .....)
and (here you can put different other condition for specific case)
```

Comment: Thanks - your right it is quite simple, but works aswell!